# Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, npm, chart.js

I've installed `chart.js` using npm by : `npm install chart.js --save-dev`, in `"resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js"` 
I refer to it by: 
`require('chart.js');` 
Then in my console `npm run dev` and finally it's successfully compiled in `"public/js/app.js"`, however when I try to use it in my view as follow

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script><script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
......... </script>
```

the browser returns

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined.

How come it's declared in `app.js` and can't refer to it ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you're using strict "use strict" mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in app.js, is it wrapped in a function? It sounds like it's not part of the global namespace, despite being present in app.js.

Comment: how to do it in yii2? can you please see my related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255144/yii2-chart-is-not-defined)?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using es6 you might need to change the way you require it.

from the docs:
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

```
// Using CommonJS
var Chart = require('chart.js')
var myChart = new Chart({...})

// ES6
import Chart from 'chart.js'
let myChart = new Chart({...})

// Using requirejs
require(['path/to/Chartjs'], function(Chart){
var myChart = new Chart({...})
})
```